# What does "Get a run in" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

While watching [Burn After Reading](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0887883/) Harry Pfarrer uses the following phrase at times when he's leaving a place:

> Maybe I can get a run in

What does it mean?
I searched in google a bit, and I found [this](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/run-in) and [this](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/run-in?q=get%20a%20run%20in) but I'm not sure what the correct meaning is.

Comment: Without further context my best guess would be that he's talking about a session of running/jogging, for exercise.  But there is insufficient context (ie, none at all) to tell with any certainty.

Comment: Base ball? Get a run in to home base. No, jogging is a better guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In idiomatic U.S. English, a person who says, while leaving one location, "Maybe I can get a run in" is suggesting the possibility that he or she can find time for a brief run for exercise (what used to be called a *jog*) before the next item on the person's schedule must be attended to.

As that description suggests, the phrase often come up under unplanned circumstances—when, for example, a late morning meeting breaks up early and the person has time for a long lunch (or maybe a run and a quick lunch) before the scheduled slate of afternoon activities at work begin.

A fuller expression of the idea—though not a wording that someone would be likely to use, since the shorter idiomatic form is available—might be this:

> Maybe I can get a quick run squeezed in among my other accomplishments for the day, if I do it sometime between now and when my next scheduled activity begins.